# Retrieve end effector pose in MoveIt

Tags: moveit, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a node that has to publish the pose (and if possible twist) of the end effector.

My robot publishes a tf which I think could be used in this fashion. But I would also like to benefit from MoveIt's high-level API which allows to give names to the end effectors.

Additional question: if you have anything for the end effector twist, that would be very helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89006/retrieve-end-effector-pose-in-moveit/) by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2013-10-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-09**:
With twist do you mean how it is oriented or how it is moving (i.e. velocities)?

**Comment by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on 2013-10-09**:
Yes, as in geometry_msgs::Twist

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-10-09**:
@Flavian has also posted this question here, see more answers in this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/moveit-users/zFMzGqkVBuc/cO7Pzc34qVMJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/zFMzGqkVBuc) by Simon Jansen:

> Assuming you're using the high-level
> movegroup interface, could you not do
> something like this:
>
> ```
> moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup *group; 
> group = new moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup("arm");
> group->setEndEffectorLink("hand_left");
> geometry_msgs::PoseStamped current_pose =
> group->getCurrentPose();
> ```

but this is if you want to define a new group. If you want to use the group linked to your previous end-effector you should do:

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("your end-effector");
group.getCurrentPose();
```

---

Originally posted by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) with karma: 112 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is your end effector a link with a frame id?

Then you already have everything. Just get the tf transform for this frame_id. This gives you a pose that contains position and orientation.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on 2013-10-09**:
There is a precise notion of end effector in the MoveIt API (http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start#STEP_6:_Label_End_Effectors) which I would need to use.
Plus, in the MoveIt API, if you have a link you can get the FK. However I fail at seeing the big picture.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-10-09**:
I agree with @dornhege. Just use TF, using MoveIt only for this is overkill.

**Comment by [Flavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5572/flavian/) on 2013-10-09**:
While I agree with your point, TF doesn't semantically take advantage of the end effector naming from MoveIt. Say you have at least two end effectors that you defined (e.g fingers on a hand) and your node accept an "end_effector" property, it's easier to switch from a user point of view.